# Sort products using Select element in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am basically creating a website and it is a site that sells coffee and beans. I need to find a way using PHP to create like a drop-down list that can sort the products by their types. What is the simplest way of going about this? I am quite new to PHP and not too sure how to go about it.
i tried this code below and when i choose the value of the Select nothing changes on the page.
this is my php code which bring all the products in that Category.

```
          <?php
          $servername = "localhost:3307";
          $dBUsername = "root";
          $dBPassword = "";
          $dBName = "beanery";

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed".mysqli_connect_errpr());
        }

          $allproducts=mysqli_query($conn,"select Pname,price,pro_pic from products where Category='COFFEE'");

        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($allproducts);  

          for ($i=0;$i< $rows ; $i++){
              list($Name,$Price,$Image)= mysqli_fetch_array($allproducts);
              echo "
               <div class='col-lg-4 mb-5 col-md-6'>
              <div class='wine_v_1 text-center pb-4'>
          <a href='shop-single.html' class='thumbnail d-block mb-4'><img src='images/$Image' alt='Image' class='img-fluid'></a>
          <div>
            <h3 class='heading mb-1'><a href='shop-single.php'>$Name</a></h3>
            <span class='price'>$Price</span>
          </div>


          <div class='wine-actions'>

            <h3 class='heading-2'><a href='shop-single.php'>$Name</a></h3>
            <span class='price d-block'>$Price</span>


            <a href='cart.html' class='btn add'><span class='icon-shopping-bag mr-3'></span> Add to Cart</a>
          </div>
        </div>
              </div> 
              ";
          }
        ?>
```

and then i entered a select element which contain the types like below :

```
<label>Sort by:</label>
          <select id="sortCoffee">
    <option selected>Type</option>
    <option id="capsules">Capsules</option>
    <option id="beans">Coffee beans</option>
          </select>
```

and i tried this code to sort only the first type which is "Capsules" and when i choose this type only the product with that type will appear :

```
if (isset($_POST['capsules'])) {
        $sorted1 = mysqli_query($conn,"select Pname,price,pro_pic from products where Kind='Capsules'");
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($sorted1);  

          for ($i=0;$i< $rows ; $i++){
              list($Name,$Price,$Image)= mysqli_fetch_array($sorted1);
              echo "
               <div class='col-lg-4 mb-5 col-md-6'>
              <div class='wine_v_1 text-center pb-4'>
          <a href='shop-single.html' class='thumbnail d-block mb-4'><img src='images/$Image' alt='Image' class='img-fluid'></a>
          <div>
            <h3 class='heading mb-1'><a href='shop-single.php'>$Name</a></h3>
            <span class='price'>$Price</span>
          </div>


          <div class='wine-actions'>

            <h3 class='heading-2'><a href='shop-single.php'>$Name</a></h3>
            <span class='price d-block'>$Price</span>


            <a href='cart.html' class='btn add'><span class='icon-shopping-bag mr-3'></span> Add to Cart</a>
          </div>
        </div>
              </div> 
              ";
          }    
        }
```

but nothing changes .
can you please help me know where i did something wrong, and help me know how to do it?
i'll appreciate it

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, but it is a very important issue. The 'root' account is for mysql administration only and should have a password. Use a different account on www with a password and only the permissions you need to use. Otherwise you are asking for a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

To read as $_POST you should use

```
<select name="sortCoffee">
```

and

```
if (isset($_POST['sortCoffee'])) {
```

when you select Capsules, $_POST['sortCoffee'] will be 'Capsules'